# Pass array of objects containing arrays to MVC action via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, arrays, stringify

Say I have a javascript object like:

```
function Parent(n, c) {
    this.Name = n;
    this.Children = c;
}

var p = new Parent("asdf", [1,2,3]);
```

And I want to pass an array of the `parent` object and its children to an MVC 4 controller via JSON.

How would I go about formatting the ajax request? I've seen [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336721/mvc-4-pass-complex-object-to-async-controller-action) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690272/pass-an-array-of-objects-using-jquery-load-to-mvc-3) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824773/passing-an-array-of-javascript-classes-to-a-mvc-controller) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346751/how-to-pass-json-object-to-controller-method-in-asp-net-mvc-4) [questions](http://www.google.ca/search?q=pass+complex+object+array+to+mvc) along these lines, although none that use an array as a member variable.

This is what I have so far:

```
var parents = [];
parents.push(new Parent("qwer", "child1"));
parents.push(new Parent("sdfg", 12345));
parents.push(new Parent("zxcv", [4,5,6]));

$.ajax({
    url: MakeUrl("Ctlr/Action"),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({
       parents : parents
    }),
    success: function (data, state, xhr) {
        $("#someDiv").html(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, state, err) {
        Utility.displayError(xhr.reponseText);
    }
});
```

The result of stringify actually looks reasonable:

```
"{"parents":[{"Name":"qwer","Value":"child1"}, {"Name":"sdfg","Value":12345}, {"Name":"zxcv","Value":[4,5,6]}]}"
```

Here is the Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Action(IEnumerable<Parent> parents) {
    ...
}
```

And in case it's relevant, the server-side `Parent` object:

```
public class Parent {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Children { get; set; }
}
```

`Children` is an `object` because it is sometimes another data type - I realize this may be a slight code-smell, but the ultimate function of this class is to pass arbitrary parameters to our reporting engine.

The simple data types seem to work just fine in this way (date, integer, string, etc), but the `Children` array just comes through as `{object}`, which as far as I can tell is not even a string, but some generic System object. Is there a way to do this in MVC without resorting to, say, pushing it into a string and parsing it out?

Comment: Have you tried `dynamic` instead of `object`? The issue here is that `object` isn't inherently convertible to an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Using `dynamic` gives the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I've settled for submitting a flat list via javascript, which is then built out on the server side.

The javascript:

```
var parents = [];
parents.push(new Parent("asdf", "qwer"));
parents.push(new Parent("zxcv", 123456));

[4,5,].forEach(function (e, i) {
    params.push(new Parent("Children[" + i + "]", e));
});
```

Which looks like this after `JSON.stringify`:

```
[{"Name":"asdf","Value":"qwer"},{"Name":"zxcv","Value":123456},{"Name":"Children[0]","Value":4},{"Name":"Children[1]","Value":5},{"Name":"Children[2]","Value":6}]
```

And is then un-flattened in the Controller via the following function:

```
private IEnumerable<Parent> Unzip(IEnumerable<Parent> parameters) {
    var unzipped = new Dictionary<string, Parent>();
    var r = new Regex(@"(.*)\[.*\]");

    foreach (var p in parameters)
    {
        var match = r.Match(p.Name.ToString());
        if (match.Success)
        {
            var name = match.Groups[1].Value;
            if (!unzipped.ContainsKey(name))
                unzipped.Add(name, new Parent() { Name = name, Value = new List<object>() { } });

            ((List<object>)(unzipped[name].Value)).Add(p.Value);
        }
        else
            unzipped.Add(p.Name, p);
    }

    return unzipped.Values;
}
```